# Passing parameters to a window call in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm new to programming against Windows calls, and I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a parameter to the lpfnWndProc function.  I have the following code:

```
HWND hwnd;
WNDCLASS wc1 = {0};

wc1.lpszClassName = TEXT( "sample" );
wc1.hInstance     = 0;
wc1.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
wc1.lpfnWndProc   = DepthWndProc;
```

Note the line `wc1.lpfnWndProc = DepthWndProc;`  Am I able to pass DepthWndProc a parameter?  If so, what does the syntax look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a function pointer here, not making a call.  Thus no passing of arguments.

Having to store extra state with a HWND isn't unusual, a very common requirement for a C++ class wrapper around a window for example.  You should keep a map<> to help you retrieve the wrapper object from the window handle value.  Using SetWindowLongPtr() with GWLP_USERDATA is possible too but less ideal if you don't control the window creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call DepthWndProc directly and pass its parameters, but why on earth would you do that?  That's not how windows programming works.

You are giving windows a function to call whenever it has a message to send to your window.